# Declare vector in C#

Tags: c#, vector

```
private Vector addTwoVectorsExample() {
    // Create two Vector structures.
    Vector vector1 = new Vector(20, 30);
    Vector vector2 = new Vector(45, 70);
    Vector vectorResult = new Vector();

    // Add the vectors together. 
    // vectorResult is equal to (65, 100).
    vectorResult = Vector.Add(vector1, vector2);

    return vectorResult;

}
```

When i declare, it show error in **Vector vector1 = new Vector(20, 30);**

> How can i call vector in **C#**.

Comment: Add reference to System.Windows;  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector(v=vs.110).aspx  --- This is probably a WPF thing (since it is in WindowsBase.dll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is the **missing** **reference** to the assembly. The assembly you need calls `WindowsBase` and is part of `System.Windows`.

You can add it with the following instruction:

1. Right-click on `References`, which is in your project structure
2. Click on `Add references`

[image]

3. Click on `Assemblies` or type `Windows` into the search field
4. Select the assembly: `WindowsBase`
5. Press on `OK`
6. `Rebuild` your solution

[image]